# Can I stop rsync daemon on port 443 from using ssh?

Tags: debian, rsync

I have a machine on the LAN with an rsync daemon (on Debian Squeeze) running on default port 873 with this config:

```
[sync]
    path = /mnt/hux/WORK
    read only = false
    uid = dco
```

I'm connecting with it as follows:

```
rsync -az --delete --force --progress /path/to/stuff/ hostname::sync/stuff
```

That works fine.

Now I have another server, outside the firewall, which blocks port 873. So, I have rsync listening on port 443 instead, but everything else is configured the same. However, when I try connecting to it like this:

```
rsync -avvz --delete --force --progress /path/to/stuff/ hostname:443::sync/stuff
```

I see:

```
opening connection using: ssh hostname rsync --server -vvvlogDtprze.iLsf --delete --force . 443::sync/stuff
```

And it asks me for a password. Is there some way I can change the port and not have rsync assume I want to use SSH? I'd like to just use rsync as I'm doing on the LAN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use

```
rsync -avvz .... /path/to/stuff/ rsync://hostname:443/sync/stuff
```

The doublecolon does not support a port notation.

Comment: Ah - bingo! Thanks. I'd actually tried that, but not with the rsync:// notation.

Comment: You're welcome! Ran into this myself, made me strange headaches. Mixed both notations and did not see they differ in this aspect...

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `--port=443` option:

```
rsync -avvz --delete --port=443 --force --progress /path/to/stuff/ hostname::sync/stuff
```